# How does this 'let' variable works in this code?

Tags: javascript, settimeout, var, let

code1:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) { 
    setTimeout(() => { 
        console.log(i) }, 0) 
}
```

output: `5,5,5,5,5`

code2:

```
for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) { 
    setTimeout(() => { 
    console.log(i) }, 0) 
}
```

output: `0,1,2,3,4`

Can anyone help me to understand why the output of code1 is: `5,5,5,5,5`
and code2's output is: `0,1,2,3,4`

Comment: `setTimeout` is not blocking, the function passed as the first argument is executed after the loop (and any other code within the script/function containing the loop), and at that time `var` declared variable has been increased to 5. `let` declared variable is scoped inside the loop only, and every iteration round keeps the value of the variable.

Comment: You'll need to wrap your mind around [closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures), but the simplest way to think about it is that your `let` variable creates a new "[cubby hole](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/53912/68692)" in memory for each loop, so each call to `setTimeout` get's it's own value, but `var` shares a "cubby hole", so all of the `setTimeout` callbacks have to share a single value. By the time they get called, their shared value has been updated to the value 5.